# Why cant I swap a unique_ptr with a unique_ptr returned by a function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, unique-ptr

The following code will throw a warning:

warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'argument' : conversion from 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>' to 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty> &'

```
std::unique_ptr<T> foo() { return std::unique_ptr<T>( new T ); }
std::unique_ptr<T> myVar;
myVar.swap(foo());
```

I would like to know what is the proper way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `swap` member function of `std::unique_ptr` takes a non-const lvalue reference and the expression `foo()` is an rvalue as `foo` is a function returning an object (as opposed to a reference). You cannot bind an rvalue to a non-const lvalue reference.

Note that you can do the swap the other way around:

```
foo().swap(myVar);
```

The simpler thing to do is a straight initialize:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> myVar(foo());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Visual Studio doesn't support uniform initialization syntax

Comment: @Prætorian: Bother. Let me fix.

Answer (score 1):

`std::unique_ptr::swap` takes a non-`const` reference to the other pointer. You cannot bind an r-value to a non-const reference, although VC++ allows that through a non-standard extension. Hence the warning.

To get rid of the warning either store the return value of `foo` in a variable and then swap, or reverse the order of the swap.

```
foo().swap( myVar );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to swap into a temporary. You could try this instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> foo() { return std::unique_ptr<T>( new T ); }
std::unique_ptr<T> myVar1;
std::unique_ptr<T> myVar2 = foo();
myVar1.swap(myVar2);
```

**Note** this is not specific to `std::unique_ptr`. The following would be illegal for the same reason:

```
void foo(std::string& s) { .... }
std::string bar() { .... }

foo(bar());
```

Comment: Whats wrong with swapping into a temporary? This was not a warning in VS11

Comment: @aCuria the language doesn't allow you to bind non-const references to temporaries. The logic is that it doesn't make sense to change something that will disappear immediately.

Comment: +1 for the reply, but I think in my case it makes sense for it to disappear (dtor gets called) immediately. I am using it for graphics resources (say a texture) that are expected to be screen-sized. When the screen resolution is changed, the old texture should be swapped out for a new one and the old one destroyed... hence I want to do texture.swap(newtexture);